# Inserting data from database into array and imploding that data into textarea

Tags: php, arrays, textarea

I have almost 100 lines of data in a table. I want to insert that data into an array and displaying that data into a textarea.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$dbcon = mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "pass", "databasename");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    mysqli_select_db($dbcon, "databasename") or die("database not found!!!");
    $r = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT field FROM table"); // Run the query.
    echo "<form method='post' action='' target=''>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }   
    echo "<textarea rows='5' cols='25' name='quote' wrap='physical' class='textarea' readonly onClick='this.select()'>" . implode("\n", $data) .  "</textarea>";
    echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

Only thing that was displayed in the textarea was "Array" almost hundred times.

I just want to know how to retrieve content from array into a textarea. If the other code is wrong. Please guide me.. as i am newbie in php.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest testing with mysqli_fetch_assoc: http://devdocs.io/php/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an array offset to point an index to the fields fetched from the db.

its `$data[]=$row['field'];` NOT `$data[]=$row;`

Comment: thanks man.. it worked..on my side.. its a very silly mistake.